# why does a file downloaded from server above 32kb is automatically reduced to a size of 32 kb when I download it through sftp in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, sftp

I am trying to download multiple files from a server to my local in that according to my observation the files above 33kb were automatically reduced to 32kb and when they first get downloaded i am getting their size as 0 kb, after i refresh for multiple times its getting its data that too with reduced size.Is there any way to read the .xlsx file directly from the server in node?

```
`for (year; year < currentYear; year++) {
  for (var index = 1; index < noOfMonths; index++) {
                            var month = index > 9 ? "" + index : "0" + index;
                                // fs.exists(config.sample.filePath + year + '-' + month + '.xlsx', function(exists) {

                            sftp.fastGet(config.sample.filePath + year + '-' + month + '.xlsx', downloadedFilePath + year + '-' + month + '.xlsx', function (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                if (err) {
                                    logger.error("errrr is", err);
                                    reject(err);
                                }
                                logger.info("file downloaded");
                                conn.end();
                                started = false;


                                        });
                                // });
                        }
                    }
                    resolve();
                  });
            }).connect({
                host: config.sample.host,
                port: config.sample.port,
                username: config.sample.username,
                privateKey: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath, 'utf8')
            });`
```

Comment: You resolve too early - you must resolve only after the file has been downloaded at conn.end (just like the reject which is where it belongs).

Comment: Where do I place it to make it work properly? And is there any way that we can read .Xlsx file directly from server? @Lucero

Comment: As I wrote already place it just after conn.end

Comment: Ok sorry I have missed it and thanks.. @Lucero

Comment: that didnt resolve the problem @Lucero